# Spring / Accessing the current applicationContext in one bean's factory-method

Tags: java, spring, scala

Is there a possibility to get the actual reference to the current `ApplicationContext` ? :

```
    package myPackage;
    public class AFactory {

       public static A createA() {
          // I need to access to the current instance of ApplicationContext here, passing it to another object's method for example 
       }

    }
```

In my `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean id="myBeanA" class="myPackage.AFactory" factory-method="createA">
</bean>
```

**UPDATE --------------------------------------------------------**

I thought an example with Java would be more popular and would work in Scala but it's trickier in Scala due to the fact that "static" method are defined outside the class:

```
object ActorSystemFactory {

  var applicationContext: ApplicationContext = _

  def createActorSystem = {
    val system = ActorSystem("AkkaScalaSpring")
    SpringExtensionImpl(system)(applicationContext)
    system
  }
}

class ActorSystemFactory extends ApplicationContextAware {

  def setApplicationContext(context: ApplicationContext) {
    ActorSystemFactory.applicationContext = context
  }

}
```

For those who know Scala, here Spring warns logically about the fact that there isn't  `createActorSystem` static method in the class.

Has someone ever handled this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your bean implements ApplicationContextAware

```
public class AFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, just testing it :) I'll let you know

Comment: No problem, I think I will valid your answer, since it's the good answer regarding Java. And post another one for Scala :) Thank you!